# How many perks can you get?

Tags: fallout-4

I am assuming that there is a maximum level in Fallout 4 and because taking perks is tied to leveling, there is a presumable maximum number of perks that you can take.  Is there a maximum level in Fallout 4?  And by extension, is there a maximum number of perks that you can take?

Comment: TL;DR : There is no level cap in Fallout 4, hence technically infinite amount of perks as well.

Comment: @CoqPwner Not "infinite". But still, "all of them".